# What parameters would sorting algorithm factory have?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm thinking of creating software generating all possible sorting algorithms by specified requirements, and best fitting algorithm. What real-life requirements would you specify for that software? How would you specify them.

My suggestions are:

```
getSortingAlgorithm(int memorySize, int timeConstraintInMillisec);

//getSortingAlgorithm("O(n)", "O(n*log(n))");
getSortingAlgorithm(AssymptomaticConstaint memoryConstraint, AssymptomaticConstaint timeConstraint);
```

Any other ideas of hardening, easing these constraints?

Answer (score 0):

**number of elements** and **cache**'s size/type might also be a concideration, in order to optimize the sort's cache performance.

Also a boolean indicating if the elements has an **int value**, since integer sorting is not bounded to comparasions based algorithms.

**Number of threads** to use might be also an issue: Try to make parallel algorithms as well in your library.

Answer (score 0):

you can have stable/unstable parameter also.

for example bubble sort and selection sort both have time complexity: O(n2), memory: O(1)

but bubble sort is stable. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts

Answer (score 0):

Optimize for speed vs storage.

Re storage, cap max storage and use files for "backing store" ("chunked" sort).

Maintain order of identical items (or not).

Index sort?

Stability vs best average speed vs taking advantage of "almost sorted" data set.

Size of data set -- for smaller ones a simpler sort with less setup is better.

Size of keys -- this affects the data structures used.